# Facebook: JS SDK and PHP SDK not working together properly

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

My page to log the user in using JS SDK:

```
<? header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi NAV OUR STP IND DEM"');?>
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  if(!window.console){ window.console = {log: function(){} }; }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function()
  {
    FB.init({
      appId  : 'xxx',
      status : true, // check login status
      cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });

  };

  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());

  function fbLogin() {
           FB.login(function (response) {
                   if (response.authResponse) {

                       FB.api('/me', function (response) {

                           window.location = "tester.php";

                       });
                   } else {

                       fbLogin();
                   }
               }
               , {perms:'user_birthday, user_location'});
       }

    </script>

<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" ONCLICK="fbLogin()" value="login">
```

The page the user is redirected to on login (tester.php):

```
<? header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi NAV OUR STP IND DEM"'); ?>
<?php
session_start();

$fbconfig['appid' ] = "xxx";
$fbconfig['secret'] = "xxx";

$user            =   null;
try{
    include_once "facebook.php";
}
catch(Exception $o){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($o);
    echo '</pre>';
}

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user){

     $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

}

else
{
echo "no logged user";
}   
echo $user;
echo $access_token;

?>
<pre>
    <?php print_r($_COOKIE);
    print_r($_SESSION); ?>
</pre>
```

I've noticed that the access token is not set the first time the user gets redirected to tester.php. It just returns "appID|appSecret". Note that the user ís returned correctly. Hitting refresh updates the access_token to a valid one.
When I add a little delay before the redirect (`setTimeout(function() {window.location = "tester.php";},1250);`) everything is OK and I get a valid access token. I'm not to keen on implementing the delay, since there's no way of telling how long the delay should be. Is this a known bug?

Info: this problem only happens the first time the user visits the app. Once the users authorized the app previously, it works fine.

Comment: Anyone who can reproduce this bug? Or is it just me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it's due to network latency: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/476478799137399

Comment: Is it...? I'm not so sure after reading the reply's. I keep wondering why I seem to be the only one with this (pretty basic) problem...

Answer (score 0):

It's not because of a Latency! It's because the csfrToken check fails at the first request.

```
See base_facebook.php -> getCode()
```

The first call will always return false (Line:698). If you change this line to

```
return $_REQUEST['code'];
```

first call works just fine, too.

Comment: Interesting... Any idea why the php sdk was designed that way? And also: if it always fails at first request, then why doesn't it fail when adding a delay before redirection to that page?